# Running a loop on preset conditions in python

Tags: python, loops, oop

I created a class to solve maths problems of the sort a*b-c. However, I want function only to run if a*b-c is in range (0,100). When I run my code, it just continues to print "out of range". Instead, I would like it to try a*b-c until the result falls in the desired range (i.e., between 0 and 100). Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

```
#MULTIPLIZIEREN

class Multiplizieren:
    def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name
    self.a = rdm.randint(5,20)
    self.b = rdm.randint(4,50)
    self.c = rdm.randint(2,200)

def punktstrich(self):
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        c = self.a*self.b-self.c
        if c < 0 or c > 100:
            print('OUT OF RANGE')
            return
        else:
            print(self.a, '*', self.b, '-', self.c, '=', self.a*self.b-self.c)
            finished = True
            return c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random as rdm
class Multiplizieren:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.a = rdm.randint(5,20)
        self.b = rdm.randint(4,50)
        self.c = rdm.randint(2,200)

    def x(self):
        finished = False
        while not finished:
            c = self.a*self.b-self.c
            if c < 0 or c > 100:
                print('OUT OF RANGE')
                self.__init__(self.name)
            else:
                print(self.a, '*', self.b, '-', self.c, '=', self.a*self.b-self.c)
                finished = True
                return c

d = Multiplizieren('h')
d.x()
```

Just call `self.__init__(self.name)` to reinitialize your class when you are out of range instead of `return`, this will give you new values for a, b and c

---

Just a side note on `__init__()`: It's a special function that gets called automatically when you create an object, but you can still call it like a regular function.

Comment: thank you so much - that solves it perfectly!!! Calling __init__() is very useful for this purpose!

Comment: you're welcome. If you feel this has answer your question, feel free to accept it as an answer, else you can wait for someone else to provide an answer that fits your need better :D

Comment: Just found the answer check-mark. Thanks for the reminder, @MooingRawr

Also, on the topic of calling __init_(): This could be used as a simple factory to create objects as well, am I correct?

Comment: you should use __new__() if you are wanting to build a factory, but I'm not very clear on what you are trying to do, so sorry